# Wordpress - getting images from db stored as blob data

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, blob

I have a form uploading to database and storing images as blob. I cannot get them to output.

Upload code:

```
$image =  strip_tags(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
$image_name = strip_tags($_FILES['image']['name']);
$image_size = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
if($image_size == FALSE) {
    echo 'An image has not been uploaded';
} else {
$wpdb->insert( 
    $table, 
    array( 
        'title' => $title,
        'description' => $description,
        'brand' => $brand,
        'img_name' => $image_name,
        'img' => $image,
    )
);
```

Code to display the image:

```
$product_id = get_query_var('id');

$image = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM  products WHERE id = $product_id");

header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");

echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_decode($image[0]->img).'" />';
```

I've also tried calling a separate file `get.php` but that didnt work either e.g.

```
echo '<img src="/wp-content/themes/theme/scripta/get.php?id=' . $product_id . '" />';
```

with the following in `get.php`

```
$id = $_GET['id'];

$image = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM  products WHERE id = $id");

header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");

print_r($image);
```

What do I need to change to get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting *all* information in the table for that product id, and then trying to display it as an image. You need to access the image from the results array or `SELECT` just the image e.g. use `get_var` instead of `get_results` and select `img` instead of `*`:

```
$product_id = get_query_var('id');
$image = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT img FROM products  WHERE id = ".$product_id);
```

By the way, this leave you open to SQL injection, so you really should use `$wpdb->prepare` to include a variable in your query, e.g.

```
$image = $wpdb->get_var( 
    $wpdb->prepare("SELECT img FROM products  WHERE id = %d", $product_id)  
);
```

**BLOB size limitation**

Note that a BLOB in MYSQL is limited to 64kb. If your images are larger than this, you will need to use a MEDIUMBLOB which is 16MB

**Save the image path instead of directly in the database as a BLOB**

A more practical solution is to save just the path.

To do this, you will need to create a folder to upload the images to (e.g. in my code below, its in the web root and called `myimages`), and a new VARCHAR or TEXT column in your database (its called `img_path` in the example below).

```
/* 1. Define the path to the folder where you will upload the images to, 
      Note, this is relative to your web root. */ 
define (MY_UPLOAD_DIR, "myimages/");

$imagefilename = basename( $_FILES['image']['name']);

/* 2. define the full path to upload the file to, including the file name */
$fulluploadpath = get_home_path(). MY_UPLOAD_DIR . $imagefilename;

$image_name = strip_tags($_FILES['image']['name']);
$image_size = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

/* 3. Do your validation checks here, e.g. */
if($image_size == FALSE) {
    echo 'The image was not uploaded';
} 
/* 4. if everything is ok, copy the temp file to your upload folder */
else if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $fulluploadpath )) {
    /* 5. if the file was moved successfully, update the database */
    $wpdb->insert( 
        $table, 
        array( 
            'title' => $title,
            'description' => $description,
            'brand' => $brand,
            'img_name' => $image_name,
            'img_path' => MY_UPLOAD_DIR . $imagefilename, /* save the path instead of the image */
        )
    ); 

} else {
    //Display an error if the upload failed
    echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
}
```

To retrieve the image from the database and display it:

```
$product_id = get_query_var('id');
/* query the database for the image path */
$imagepath = $wpdb->get_var( 
    $wpdb->prepare("SELECT img_path FROM products  WHERE id = %d", $product_id)  
);

/* 6. Display the image using the path. 
      Because the path we used is relative to the web root, we can use it directly 
      by prefixing it with `/` so it starts at the webroot */ 
if ($imagepath)
    echo '<img src="/'.$imagepath.'" />';
```

The code above is untested, but the basic idea is there. Also, it won't work if a file with the same name already exists, so you might want to consider adding a timestamp to the name to make it unique.

**Ref**:

- [PHP POST method uploads](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)
- [move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

Comment: What is "not working"? That doesn't tell us much. What have you tried to debug this - is the image not being returned, is it being returned but not being displayed properly, or are you getting any result from the database at all?

Comment: I get nothing returned when I run the `$wpdb->prepare` option however with the first option from your comment I get `<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,">` if I inspect the code. If I run `print_r($img)` I see all the images data.

Comment: OK, we'll concentrate on getting that working first. Did you try using `echo '<img src="'.base64_decode($img).'" />';` to display it?

Comment: Yep `$image = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT img FROM products WHERE id = $product_id"); echo '<img src="'.base64_decode($image).'" />';` returns `<img src="">`

Comment: What happens when you try `header("Content-type: image/jpeg"); echo $image;`? Also, what is the column type in the database, and what size is the image you are uploading?

Comment: I get a load of `����JFIFHH���Photoshop 3.08BIM-Z%Gt© Robert Eldrim, Medljus8BIM%]$|�_�Bۚ$V� N�8BIM-Z%Gt© Robert Eldrim, Medljus8BIM%]$|�_�Bۚ$V� N���C !"$"$��C����"��` … Column type is `blob` and image size is 352kb

Comment: @creativemonkey A BLOB has a limit of 64kb, so that's probably whats causing this issue - its not saving all the image data so it won't display. A MEDIUMBLOB is 16MB so change it to that and try again.

Comment: Would you be able to tell me how to store the path in the db and then store the uploaded image in a folder ?

Comment: @creativemonkey Yes, that is a much more practical way of doing it! I'll update my answer... give me a few minutes

Comment: So much better, and thank you so much for all your help! … All I had to change was `basename( $_FILES['Filename']['name'] );` to `basename( $_FILES['image']['name'] );` which refers to the form field I'm using. Thanks again!

Comment: @creativemonkey Glad I could help! Sorry for mixing up the $_FILES key - I was mixing your code with other code I had, I'll update my answer for anyone else who might find this useful :)