# How to get results in form of tables with column titles in wordpress?

Tags: database, wordpress

```
    <form action="" method="post" name="myForm">
    Filter <input id="isbn" type="text" name="isbn" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /> </form>
    <?php 
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    global $wpdb;
     $table_name = "isbn";  // change this to your table name
     $field = $_POST['isbn']; // change this to your isbn field $_POST['ISBN'];
    $retrieve_data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $table_name where isbn = '".$field."'");
    foreach ($retrieve_data as $retrieved_data) {

    echo $retrieved_data->Title; 
    echo $retrieved_data->Image;  // for image
     echo $retrieved_data->Isbn; 
     }
    }
```

// I have this php code for accessing data from my database table. but the result is not coming in desired form. i am sending some screenshots which are describing my situations.
[This image contain my database table structure and record containing title, image and isbn column.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SqTi.png)

[This is the output which i am getting after applying above query and image is also not displaying in browser.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyVa5.png)

[This type of output i want in my browswer after someone enter isbn number of book in search form.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9C2O.png)

Can someone please provide me code for this?

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/46306180/7410804

Answer (score 0):

Try adding **ARRAY_A** in the **get_results** method argument like below.

```
$retrieve_data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $table_name where isbn = '".$field."'", ARRAY_A);
```

and then for displaying image try

```
foreach ($retrieve_data as $retrieved_data) {
 echo $retrieved_data['Title']; 
 echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $retrieved_data['Image'] ).'"/>';  // for image
 echo $retrieved_data['Isbn']; 
}
```

Comment: No this is not working . even now i am not getting title and isbn.

Comment: edited the second part of code now, try again now .. :)

i changed $retrieved_data->Title to $retrieved_data['Title'] now

Comment: yes! That Works! but the only thing that is creating issue is that the resulted output doesn't came in form of table as i describe in the question.... i.e (Image 3)